# как зафиксировать прокрутку внутри NestedScrollView?

Tags: android-studio, xml, recyclerview, coordinator-layout, nested-scrollview

Вот разметка активити. Мне нужно чтобы верхние элементы внутри `NestedScrollView` остались видимыми при достижении верхней точки.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/run_back"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarfix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ask_faq"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardView5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            style="@style/AppThemeWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editAsk"
                style="@style/AppThemeWhite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/ur_question"
                android:textColor="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorLink="@color/text_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvAsk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Вот эти элементы должны остаться видимыми, а список RecyclerView должен прокручиваться дальше.]

[image: Но они начинают прокручиваться параллельно с RecyclerView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри `NestedScrollView` они не могут оставаться, так как он прокручивает все свое содержимое, нужно между вашим `AppBar` и `NestedScrollView` установить контейнер, который будет расположен под `AppBar` и под которым будет расположен `NestedScrollView`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/run_back"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarfix"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/ask_faq"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardView5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Отсюда убираем `NestedScrollView` и `RecyclerView` создаем для них отдельную разметку, назовем разметку, например, content_with_recycle. И ставим `ConstraintLayout`, а затем устанавливаем его якорем под `AppBarLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbarfix" // Тут его заякорили
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
            style="@style/AppThemeWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/text_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editAsk"
                style="@style/AppThemeWhite"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:hint="@string/ur_question"
                android:textColor="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorHint="@color/text_light"
                android:textColorLink="@color/text_light"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/askBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="28dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ну и тут подключаем созданную разметку `content_with_recycle`:

```
     <include layout="@layout/content_with_recycler" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Содержимое разметки `content_with_recycle`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bottom_radius_background"
android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAsk"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

P.S. Так как `NestedScrollView` и `RecyclerView` прокручиваются оба, для ресайкла вызовите метод `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` чтобы не было конфликта двух скроллов.